# Создать хранимую процедуру (Transact-SQL), которая возвращает true или false

Tags: sql-server

Существует 2 таблицы:
*Transacation(Customer_Id, RelatedProduct)* и *CustomerProduct(CustomerId, CustomerProduct)*.
Необходимо создать хранимую процедуру с двумя входными параметрами (*@Customer* и *@Product*, к примеру) и одним выходным(@result), который выводит true или false,  в зависимости от того является ли RelatedProduct этого Customer'а.
Простой запрос создал, но не получается перевести его в процедуру.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId, RelatedProduct
    FROM Transacation,CustomerProduct 
    WHERE CustomerProducts.CustomerId=Transaction.CustomerId 
    AND CustomerProducts.CustomerProduct=Transaction.RelatedProduct
    ORDER BY CustomerId
    GO
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается? Объявите две переменные, заполните, и параметрезируйте свой запрос.

Comment: Непонятен синтаксис с выходным параметром. Что и как выводить.

Comment: можно подробнее ваш кейс? куда планируется возвращать? частота обращений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. в SQL Server не существует типа данных `boolean`  для возврата `True`/`False`, для типа возвращаемого значения воспользуемся типом [Bit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql), значения будем интерпретировать следующим образом: `0 - False` и `1 - True`

Пример процедуры с вашим запросом:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_product_check 
    @Customer int
    ,@Product int
    ,@result bit OUTPUT
AS
    set nocount ON;
    if exists
            (SELECT *
             FROM Transacation t
                inner join CustomerProduct c ON c.CustomerId = t.CustomerId  and c.CustomerProduct = t.RelatedProduct
             WHERE  @Customer = c.CustomerId and @Product = c.CustomerProduct)
        SET @result = 1
    ELSE SET @result = 0
```

Пример вызова процедуры и проверки возвращаемого значения:

```
declare @check_result bit
exec customer_product_check @Customer = 1, @Product = 1, @result = @check_result OUTPUT
select @check_result
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!